# JQuery form validation rules syntax

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I'm trying to use jquery validation with a rule/message set and can't seem to get it working. Relativeny new to JQuery, so apologies if it's a basic question. I'm trying to use document.forms[0] instead of a form ID. It works with simple validation where the field has class="required" but not if I try to introduce rules. Any help greatly appreciated. Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
                "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-        validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document.forms[0]).validate({
    rules: {
      cname: {
      required: true,
    }
    },
    messages: {
      cname: "Please enter a valid Name."
    },
  });
  });
  </script>

</head>
<body>


 <form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="">
 <fieldset>
   <legend>A simple comment form with submit validation and default messages</legend>
  <p>
     <label for="cname">Name</label>
     <em>*</em><input id="cname" name="name"/>
   </p>

   <p>
     <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
   </p>
 </fieldset>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: OT, but `$(document.forms[0])` could just as easily be `$('form:first')`

Comment: Try putting the `name` attribute as `cname` as well. I can't remember if the validator looks for the `id` or `name`.

Comment: As comment above it work with the name :) http://jsfiddle.net/peGF3/

Comment: Thanks folks. That sorted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you can just target your form by its `id`, `#commentForm`.  Secondly, the root cause of your problem was that you were improperly targeting the `input` field by its `id` attribute.  However, the `.validate()` plugin is looking for the `name` attribute, which in your case, also happened to be `"name"`.  I've changed the value of the `name` attribute in my example below just to make it more clear.

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#commentForm').validate({
        rules: {
           username: {
               required: true
           }
        },
        messages: {
           username: "Please enter a valid Name."
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="get" action="">

    <input type="text" id="cname" name="username" />

    ....
```

**[Working DEMO:](http://jsfiddle.net/egdEn/)**

http://jsfiddle.net/egdEn/

[See the online documentation for more info.](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

Comment: That's why I always make my name and ID the same word, in case my memory fails me

Answer (score 2):

I suppose I'll answer the question since my comment was correct.

Try putting the `name` attribute as "cname" as well. The validator looks for the `name` attribute.